# Flutter: Scratch card

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is the example of a scratch card in react-native, I want to implement in Flutter, But I am not getting any way to do this. I tried with `blendMode` but it is not working, and even there is no clear functionality are given in `CustomPaint` in the flutter. https://github.com/aleksik/react-scratchcard.
[image]

```
 Future<Null> main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: new Roller())));
}

class Roller extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScratchCardState createState() => new _ScratchCardState();
}

class _ScratchCardState extends State<Roller> {
  ui.Image _image;
  String _urlImage = 'assets/BedRoom.png';

  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    super.initState();

    load(_urlImage).then((j) {
      _image = j;
      print('image:${_image}');
    });
  }

  Future<ui.Image> load(String asset) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(asset);

    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
      data.buffer.asUint8List(),
    );
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return fi.image;
  }

  void _onPanStart(DragStartDetails dt) {
    print('drag start ');
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  Offset _localPosition;
  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();

      _localPosition = object.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
      _points = new List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);
    });
  }

  _onPanEnd(DragEndDetails dt) {
    _points.add(null);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _scale(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: _onPanStart,
      onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
      onPanEnd: _onPanEnd,
      onDoubleTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _points.clear();
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: ScratchCard(
              imagePath: _image, points: _points,),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _scale(context),
    );
  }
}

class ScratchCard extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image imagePath;
  List<Offset> points;
  ScratchCard({Key key, this.imagePath, this.points}) : super();
  Paint _paint = Paint();

  Rect rect, inputSubrect, outputSubrect;
  Path path = new Path();
  Paint paint1 = new Paint();
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _paint.blendMode = BlendMode.src;
    if (imagePath != null)
      canvas.drawImage(imagePath, Offset(10.0, 100.0), _paint);
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 30.0;
    _paint.blendMode = BlendMode.clear;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
        path.reset();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ScratchCard oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you have included is nowhere near complete. Please either include the rest of the code, or rewrite it in such a way that it is self-enclosed without exposing more of your code.

Comment: The problem has been solved.

Comment: That's good! If you have time it would be great if you could write out a minimal solution or at least explain what worked so that the next person who comes across this problem can use it.

Comment: Here the scratch card code in the flutter.
https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/2e74c04871ec9d659500b3920441358f

Answer (score 4):

I've created a library for scratch cards in Flutter which supports both - color and image scratchable overlays. You can get it from https://pub.dev/packages/scratcher Feedback is more than welcome!

Example:

```dart
Scratcher(
  brushSize: 30,
  threshold: 50,
  color: Colors.red,
  onChange: (value) { print("Scratch progress: $value%"); },
  onThreshold: () { print("Threshold reached, you won!"); },
  child: Container(
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    child: Text("Hidden text"),
  ),
)
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Hi @Kamil, thanks for the great control. I opened a bug related with Column widget..

Comment: Hey @bashan, thanks for the report. The issue has been fixed in the latest master branch (would be available in 1.2.1 release).